# How to check the uploaded compressed image size in PHP?

Tags: php, android, file-upload

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I need to upload image to server. I am using PHP (Laravel 5.2) for server-side. I am using Volley to connect with server. But before I uploaded I compressed the image before upload in the android. So my problem is how can I validate the file size of uploaded image in server-side?

This is how I compress in Android

```
public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        if(imgExtension!=null && imgExtension.equals("png"))
        {
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        }
        else{
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        }
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }
```

So I put the compressed string to image field and upload to server.

I upload at the server-side like this.

```
//I want to retrieve the uploaded image size here before upload
file_put_contents("my_image.jpg", base64_decode($_POST['image']));
```

So how can I check file size as I commented?

Comment: Which file size? Please be exact. I see no file to begin with.

Comment: I compressed it as a string in android. Then I retrieve it using base64_decode at server side. Then I uploaded it.

Comment: At the client size, I put that string to image field in HTTP request. Then I retrieve at server-side like this. $_POST['image'] . Not like ordinary file upload.

Comment: Yes i knew that already. But you talked about file size. I see no file. So what do you mean by it? Please answer questions instead of repeating yourself.

Comment: My point is I want to limit the uploaded file size. In this situation, I can validate file size at the client size. But client size validation is never enough. That is why I want to validate at the server side as well for security. So is that possible?If it is not possible, how can I protect clients from uploading very huge file at server-side please ?

Comment: You can check `strlen(base64_decode($_POST['image'])))` or `strlen($_POST['image']));` before saving to file.

Comment: How can I calculate file size by string length. 1 letter is equal to how much byte of file please ?

Comment: Which file? I see no file.

Comment: I mean if we compress file into string, does the string length directly proportional to file size like I am doing at the client(Android) side please?

Comment: WHERE IS THE FILE?

Comment: File is at the client side. It is string at the server side. Is there a way to check the file size that is compressed at the client size. At the server side, it is string. Is there any relation between to that string and file size ? U got that ?

Comment: SHOW THE FILE AT CLIENT SIDE. I SEE NO FILE. You dont have to repeat what you want again and again. Just answer mij question.

Comment: Hay the bitmap is the file. I chose a image file openning dialog. Then I parse the url of chosen image into bitmap. That bitmap is transformed from imge file. So how can I check that chosen file size?

Comment: There is no code with a file in your post. Nor is there a file size of that file in your code. If you do not even determine the file size before upload then you cannot check it at server side. But i wonder why you keep talking about file size. You are not sending a file. You are sending a bunch of bytes `imageBytes` which you encoded to a base64 string.

Comment: I am upgrading security of my api. I get your point. You want me to check at the client size. But for me as a backend developer, client validation is never enough. in your situation, I also need to pass file size field from client. But what if malicious user make request to my api passing mock value to file size field? One more thing, I am just asking, is there any way to protect it? If I dont protect, it is going to be a security flaw at the backend.

Comment: That is why I also asked you that string is relating to file size? For example, the longer string length, the bigger file size? Any concern?

Comment: You are not sending a file. You are sending some bytes constructed from a bitmap. So why do you keep talking of file size? `imageBytes` is sent. Talk about imageBytes.

Comment: So how can I know size of imageBytes?

Comment: imageBytes.length or imageBytes.length() or imageBytes.size(). Please try wich one is the real one.

Comment: Hay. I want to check it at the server side. Not at the client side. How can I check in php ?

Comment: That i already told you long ago.

Comment: Yep . I asked me to check string length. But what is their relationship? length 1 = how much kilo byte?

Comment: You can easily find that out yourself. And i wonder why you did not already do such tests in the last hours. What did you try untill now? Wasting your boss' time?